# Relação entre tabelas ORM

Tags: orm

Estou com uma dúvida, em relação a ORM, uso o Doctrine, mas entendendo de ORM ja ajudaria. A relação do `idAninal` da tabela `consulta`, com a tabela `Animal`, seria, `ManyToMany`, `ManyToOne`, ou `OneToMany`? Conforma UML abaixo:

[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

A partir do UML tudo que podemos saber é que não é uma relação ManyToMany, pois cada consulta tem apenas um animal, visto que ela guarda o ID do animal.

A diferença entre OneToMany e ManyToOne ocorre ao nível do ORM, não há diferença em termos de estrutura do banco. Se é o lado one da relação que guarda a referência para o many diz-se que é uma relação OneToMany. Caso o many referencie o one, então é uma ManyToOne.

Por exemplo, ao codificar isso no seu ORM, você pode escolher criar uma variável "animal" na classe "consulta" (que representaria a tabela), e acessar assim o animal de cada consulta c, fazendo um c.animal. Esse é o caso OneToMany.
Outra possibilidade seria criar a variável "consultas" na classe "animal" (que representaria a tabela animal). Assim você acessaria as consultas a partir do animal, fazendo um a.consultas. Esse seria o ManyToOne.

Se você criar as duas referências simultaneamente, então passa a ser uma relação bidirecional.